# MariaDB, MySQL - what is wrong with my Create Table Syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am trying to execute such SQL command to create table for Maria DB:

```
CREATE TABLE `sh_bom`.`stockmovements` (
  `MOVEMENTID` INT NOT NULL,
  `MOVEMENTDATE` DATETIME NULL,
  `MOVEMENTVALUE` INT NULL,
  `LEFTBEFORE` INT NULL,
  `LEFTAFTER` INT NULL,
  `COMMENTARY` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  `PARTID_FK` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MOVEMENTID`),
  INDEX `PARTID_FKNAME_idx` (`PARTID_FK` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `PARTID_FKNAME`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PARTID_FK`)
    REFERENCES `sh_bom`.`detail` (`Id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

But I get such error:

```
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
  CONSTRAINT `PARTID_FKNAME`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PARTID_FK`)
    REFERENCES `sh_b' at line 10
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `sh_bom`.`stockmovements` (
  `MOVEMENTID` INT NOT NULL,
  `MOVEMENTDATE` DATETIME NULL,
  `MOVEMENTVALUE` INT NULL,
  `LEFTBEFORE` INT NULL,
  `LEFTAFTER` INT NULL,
  `COMMENTARY` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  `PARTID_FK` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MOVEMENTID`),
  INDEX `PARTID_FKNAME_idx` (`PARTID_FK` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `PARTID_FKNAME`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PARTID_FK`)
    REFERENCES `sh_bom`.`detail` (`Id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

I have checked documentation here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/foreign-keys/
And I am sure that foreign key is defined correctly:

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]

reference_option:
    RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION | SET DEFAULT
```

What am I missing in this SQL command?

Comment: Perhaps your version of MySQL doesn't support `VISIBLE` and the parser is a little confused.

Comment: Does you version of mariadb support visible indexes?

Comment: I was trying to fit MySQL syntax into MariaDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *visible* potential error in your create table statement is that your index definition uses the keyword `VISIBLE`.  Indices in MySQL are by default visible to the optimizer.  Starting with MySQL 8+, indices can be made invisible.  If you are using a version of MySQL earlier than 8+, your syntax could cause an error.